# Variables as arguments of exponential function make equation not linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

A Linear Algebra textbook I'm reading says the equation $$e^{x+y+z}=1$$ is not linear because x, y, and z are arguments of the exponential function. But I believe taking the natural log of both sides makes this $$x+y+z=\ln(1)$$ which is linear. Why isn't the first equation linear?

Comment: I would call such an equation "equivalent to a linear equation" , but not linear. It is basically the same problem as : "Is $\frac{12}{4}$ an integer" ? A matter of taste.

Comment: @Peter I don't think much of the analogy; in fact $12/4$ _is_ an integer, no matter of taste involved.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An equation in $x,y,z$ is linear  if it has the form $$ax+by+cz=d.$$Period. The equation $e^{x+y+z}=1$ is not of that form, so it's not linear.

It's *equivalent to* the linear equation $x+y+z=0$, but it's not the same equation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the description "not linear" in this case refers only to the form of the equation, not what the equation describes (in this case, a plane). Consequently, equations describing linear objects like vectors or planes could be written in a "linear" or "not linear" form.